# TravelAdvice class

Tags: c#, beginner, json.net

I have never really had to use Json.net until now, so I'm very rusty at it. For that reason, I would appreciate it if someone could have a look over my code and let me know if the way I have done it is correct.  It works as I want it; I just need a more professional eye.

For the class `TravelAdvice`, I've used http://json2csharp.com/.

```
 public class TravelAdvice
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string WebUrl { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
        public List<Related> Related { get; set; }
        public Details3 Details { get; set; }
        public List<object> RelatedExternalLinks { get; set; }
        public ResponseInfo ResponseInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class FcoTravelAdvice : IFcoTravelAdvice
    {
        public IEnumerable<TravelAdvice> GetFcoTravelAdvice(string country)
        {

            var url = "https://www.gov.uk/api/foreign-travel-advice/british-virgin-islands.json";
            var syncClient = new WebClient();
            var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

           // JObject obj = JObject.Parse(content);
           // JArray arr = (JArray)obj["fields"];

            var fCoData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TravelAdvice>(content);

            return new[] {fCoData};

            //return test.Details.summary;
            //return fCoData.ToString();

            //DataContractJsonSerializer s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

            //using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content)))
            //{

            //var data = (RootObject)s.ReadObject(ms);
            //}


            //  return content;



        }
    }
```

Comment: There's not much code to look at here. What concerns you? I'd certainly remove the dead code (in comments), but I don't think that's what you mean by reviewing it...

Comment: Hi Dan Abramov thanks for the reply, that's what I'm wondering about, all examples I have seen used lots of code, inside the FcoTravelAdvice class I have used about 5 lines, so I was wondering if I have done it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> all examples I have seen used lots of code, inside the FcoTravelAdvice class I have used about 5 lines, so I was wondering if I have done it correctly.

If it works, you definitely have!

Still, I have a couple suggestions.

#### Don't make synchronous requests

It's 2014, and we don't write synchronous applications anymore. If your method if called from GUI app, the app will freeze until the request has completed. Imagine if user has a network problem—the app will just be unresponsive, and you don't seem to have provided any means to cancel the request.

Instead, you should use [`DownloadStringTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138332(v=vs.110).aspx) to provide asynchronous method:

```
public class FcoTravelAdvice : IFcoTravelAdvice
{
    public async Task<TravelAdvice> GetFcoTravelAdvice(string country)
    {
        var url = "https://www.gov.uk/api/foreign-travel-advice/british-virgin-islands.json";
        var client = new WebClient();
        var content = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TravelAdvice>(content);
    }
}
```

[Read about `async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) if you haven't used it yet. It's life-changing.

#### Minor considerations

- Why `fCoData` and not `fcoData`? The capitalization looks weird. Moreover, "`whateverData`" is often a bad kind of name. Why not call it `advice`? After all, that's what you're deserialising.
- I would dump `FCO` prefix from code altogether (`TravelAdvice`, `GetTravelAdvice`, `advice`). It doesn't make code more meaningful. Do you really plan to support travel advice *not* from FCO?
- Finally, why is your API always return single item, but the interface returns `IEnumerable`? It's a mystery to me.

Comment: Hi Dan thanks for the reply, "Finally, why is your API always return single item, but the interface returns IEnumerable? It's a mystery to me." I'm stuck on that bit, could not get code to work unless I did it the way I did.

Comment: @George: Just return `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TravelAdvice>(content)` and change return type to `TravelAdvice`, no?

Comment: Hi Dan, that's what I have done, thanks for the help :-)